# Upload video stored in server via API with form-data content-type

Tags: node.js, reactjs, post, axios, upload

I have a bunch of videos stored in a folder on my Node.js server and a React client app using Axios to make call to several APIs.

From my React client i get videos from my server and then I want to send them via POST request with an API. The content-type of that request has to be multipart/form-data. When i upload a video with HTML5 input i can post it with the API as you can see in the following code:

```
function testUpload(props) {
    const [upload, setUpload] = useState(null);

    useEffect( () => {
        if(upload != null) libraryUpload("testUpload", upload)
    }, [upload])

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setUpload(e.target.files[0]);
    }

    const libraryUpload = async (mediaName, media) => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("files", media);
        formData.append("name", mediaName);

        const config = {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
            }
        }

        const response = await instanceOfApi.post("/library", formData, config);
        console.log(response);
    }

    return (
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)} />
    )
}
```

I send my videos from my node server this way :

```
app.get('/video/:info', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('assets/videos/' + req.params.info, { root: __dirname });
});
```

I can display them in my client but i can not send them with my POST request because the data I receive from my server are not like what I receive when I use HTML5 input form to upload a video.

How can I convert those videos from my server into valid form data like i do using input type="file"? Should I change the way i send them from my server or is there a way to make them valid from my client?

Comment: I don't see what you are trying to achieve, you have files on server, then you send the file to client side(React), then again send back the file to node js server? Can't you use something like simple string(Video name or something) instead of transferring whole video from client to server side?

Comment: I want to upload my video in a third party server which is completely different of my node js server, this is why I make a POST request using the third  party's API

Comment: The videos are publicly available? Even without them being publicly avail there are other approaches which would be more efficient than transferring video two times.

Comment: Videos are not publicly avalaible

Comment: https://muffinman.io/blog/uploading-files-using-fetch-multipart-form-data/

Comment: It does not solve my problem, I already can upload video when i use input file, and no matter i delete Content-type headers or not, the boundary is automatically set. I need to be able to convert the videos i sent from my server in form-data similar to what i get with input file